# 403 CSRF token error after setting csrf token to browser in GOFIBER

Tags: go, csrf-token, go-fiber

In GoFiber, After setting the csrf token to my browser, it expired soon but my expiration date is set for 1 day.

```
  app.Use(csrf.New(csrf.Config{
            KeyLookup:      "header:X-Csrf-Token",
            CookieName:     "csrf_bongo",
            CookieSameSite: "Strict",
            Expiration:     8 * time.Hour,
}))
```

From my client-side, i always sent my csrf-bongo cookie with X-Csrf-Token.

```
$axios.onRequest((config) => {
    $axios.setHeader('X-Csrf-Token', csrftoken)
    config.xsrfCookieName = "csrf_bongo"
    config.xsrfHeaderName = "X-Csrf-Token"
  })
```

After setting my csrf token, then next request response with 403 error and set my cookie blank.

[CSRF token response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJKH9.png)